# How to capture the result of a while loop into a data frame

Tags: r

I have this code

```
payment_date <- Sys.Date() -1
while(payment_date < Sys.Date() + 30) {
   payment_date <- payment_date + 1; 
   print(payment_date)
}
```

And this output:

> [1] "2017-08-07"
>   ...
>   [1] "2017-09-06"

Does anybody know how I can get all these 30 lines into a data frame?

Answer (score 0):

I could do it like this.

```
paydates <- character(30)
i <- 0

payment_date <- Sys.Date() -1
while(payment_date < Sys.Date() + 30) {
    payment_date <- payment_date + 1
    print(payment_date)
    i <- i + 1
    paydates[i] <- payment_date
}

paydates <- as.Date(paydates)
```

Then, put the resulting vector `paydates` as a column in your df.

```
result <- data.frame(paydates)
```

Note that if your real use case is this simple, it's much better to simply do

```
payment_date <- Sys.Date() + (-1:29)
```

Comment: This does not answer the question *Does anybody know how can I get all these 30 lines in a data frame?*

Comment: @RichScriven This doesn't answer the question in what way? This produces a vector. All you have to do is create a new column in the df. Just do `dat$new_col <- paydates`.

Comment: OP has no data frame to begin with.  The question is *How do I get the result of this `while` loop into a data frame?*  Read the last line of the question. I've just edited it for clarity.

Comment: @RichScriven OK, thanks. I hadn't realised that the issue was how to create a one column data frame.

Comment: thanks a lot. Appreciate your attention. I've got the solution.

Comment: Hi could the OP share the solution to the problem please?

Comment: @SamPer The solutions to the problem are the answer.s And since there is only one, it's this one. (The OP could have accepted it but didn't.)